# Python string.join ( list ) last entry with "and"

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is an elegant way to join a list of sentence parts so that the result is "a, b, and c" where the `list` is `[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]`? Specifying simply `', '.join()` achieves only "a, b, c".

( Also, I did do a few searches on this but obviously I'm not trying the write phrases because I haven't come up with anything besides enumerating the list myself. )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
L = ['a','b','c']

if len(L)>2:
    print ', '.join(L[:-1]) + ", and " + str(L[-1])
elif len(L)==2:
    print ' and '.join(L)
elif len(L)==1:
    print L[0]
```

Works for lengths 0, 1, 2, and 3+.

The reason I included the length 2 case is to avoid commas: `a and b`.

If the list is length 1, then it just outputs `a`.

If the list is empty, nothing is outputted.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `len(words)>2`, you can join the first `n-1` words using `', '`, and add the last word using standard string formatting:

```
def join_words(words):
    if len(words) > 2:
        return '%s, and %s' % ( ', '.join(words[:-1]), words[-1] )
    else:
        return ' and '.join(words)
```

Comment: was about to post the exact same answer

Comment: This assumes you will always have 3 or more words

Answer (score 1):

```
"{} and {}".format(",".join(l[:-1]),l[-1]) if len(l) > 1 else l[0]


In [25]: l =[ 'a']

In [26]: "{} and {}".format(",".join(l[:-1]),l[-1]) if len(l) > 1 else l[0]
Out[26]: 'a'

In [27]: l =[ 'a','b']

In [28]: "{} and {}".format(",".join(l[:-1]),l[-1]) if len(l) > 1 else l[0]
Out[28]: 'a and b'

In [29]: l =[ 'a','b','c']

In [30]: "{} and {}".format(",".join(l[:-1]),l[-1]) if len(l) > 1 else l[0]
Out[30]: 'a,b and c'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l = ['a','b','c']
if len(l) > 1:
    print ",".join(k[:-1]) +  " and " + k[-1]
else:print l[0]
```

exapmles:

```
l = ['a','b','c']
a,b and c

l = ['a','b']
a and b

l=['a']
a
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a robust oneliner that works with any number of elements, even 0.

```py
", ".join(l[:-2] + [" and ".join(l[-2:])])
```

using range index `:` everywhere frees you from having to handle special cases.

Note: it only works with lists because of the `+` operator.